# Range search for the strings of 3 columns

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have set of string like below
a.b.c

```
a1.b1.c1
a1.b1.c2
a1.b2.c3
a2.b1.c1
a2.b2.c2
a3.b3.c3
```

If asked for `a1.*` it should return me all the string starting from `a1`.
If asked for `a1.b1` , then should return all the string starting from `a1.b1`

All the output should be in sorted fashion ( lexicographic )

Any suggestion on datastructure, I was thinking of `Suffix Tree`.

Comment: what about a simple List and some regexp pattern matching to filter the elements?

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you.

```
String stringarray[] = {"a1.b1.c1",
"a1.b1.c2",
"a1.b2.c3",
"a2.b1.c1",
"a2.b2.c2",
"a3.b3.c3"};
String startingfrom = "a1.b1";
for(int i = 0; i < stringarray.length;i++) {
     if(stringarray[i].startsWith(startingfrom))
              System.out.println("string is : " + stringarray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your set of strings is basically fixed (not updated often), a simple sorted list would be fine.  To find all the strings with a prefix, perform a binary search on that list, finding the first string.  Then iterate from that point while strings match the prefix.

In terms of builtin Java data structures, I'd recommend using a TreeSet.

```
SortedSet<String> data = new TreeSet<String>();

Set<String> findMatching(SortedSet<String> data, String prefix) {
    String prefix = prefix.replace("*", ""); // remove unnecessary *
    String nextPrefix = prefix + '\uffff'; // a string guaranteed to be after anything matching the prefix
    // get the subset after the prefix, and then get the subset of that before the prefix
    return data.tailSet(prefix).headSet(nextPrefix, false);
}

findMatching(data, "a1.b1.*");
```

Using `nextPrefix` is a little ugly, as I have assumed that prefixes will always be sequences of `.`-separated parts, and that appending the FFFF character is the best way to get a string greater than any matching the prefix.  There may be nicer ways of doing this part.

Answer (score 0):

NavigabeeSet can do things like that and fast:

```
    NavigableSet<String> s = new TreeSet<>();
    s.addAll(Arrays.asList("a1.b1.c1", "a1.b1.c2", "a1.b2.c3", "a2.b1.c1"));
    System.out.println(s.subSet("a1.", true, "a2", false)); // a1.*
    System.out.println(s.tailSet("a1.b1"));                 // a1.b1
```

output

```
[a1.b1.c1, a1.b1.c2, a1.b2.c3]
[a1.b1.c1, a1.b1.c2, a1.b2.c3, a2.b1.c1]
```

Answer (score 0):

My function:

```
class Match
{
    public static ArrayList<String> match (String[] data, String regex)
    {
        ArrayList<String> m = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String d : data)
        {
            if (d.matches(regex))
            {
                m.add(d);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(m);

        return m;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
String data [] =
{"a1.b1.c1",
 "a1.b1.c2",
 "a1.b2.c3",
 "a2.b1.c1",
 "a2.b2.c2",
 "a3.b3.c3"};

// match using a regular expression
ArrayList<String> matched = match (data, "^a1\.b1.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 3d tree (a special case of kd-tree). Then to do search on something like `a1.b1.*`, you do a range search on `a1.b1.c1_min` and `a1.b1.c1_max`. And sort the output.

That would give you `O (n ^ (2/3) + r)` for search and `O (r log (r))` for sort, where `n` is the number of all nodes and `r` is the number of found nodes.

Search complexity follows from search complexity of a general kd-tree: `O(n ^ (1-1/k) + r)`, in case of 3d tree, `k` is 3. `^` is to the power of.